# String interpolation "Cannot convert object to primitive value at Array.toString"

Tags: typescript

I'm completely new to Typescript, but am surprised that `console.log` can render my Array correctly but String Interpolation is all "TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value...at Array.toString (native)...".

Here's the code.

```
  static async createPartsListItemsInOperations(input: Array<PartsListItemQtyInput>, authToken: string): Promise<any> {
    // console.log renders the array just fine
    console.log(input);
    // String interpolation results in TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value... at Array.toString (native)...
    const query = `mutation { createPartsListItemsInOperations(input: ${input}) { ${OperationsProvider.fields} } }`;
    const data = await this.execute(query, authToken);
    return data['createPartsListItemsInOperations'];
  }
```

at runtime the console looks like...

```
[ { operationId: '7',
    catalogIdentifier: '5c9abda',
    quantity: 1 },
  { operationId: '5',
    catalogIdentifier: '59f7775',
    quantity: 2 },
  { operationId: '4',
    catalogIdentifier: '5c9abda',
    quantity: 3 },
  { operationId: '5',
    catalogIdentifier: '5c9ab8f',
    quantity: 4 },
  { operationId: '6',
    catalogIdentifier: '5c9ab8f',
    quantity: 5 } ]
TypeError: Cannot convert object to primitive value
    at Array.toString (native)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/src/api/operations/provider.ts:184:73)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/src/api/operations/provider.ts:8:71
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/src/api/operations/provider.ts:4:12)
    at Function.createPartsListItemsInOperations (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/src/api/operations/provider.ts:123:16)
    at createPartsListItemsInOperations (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/src/api/operations/schema.ts:321:32)
    at field.resolve (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/node_modules/graphql-extensions/src/index.ts:155:61)
    at resolveFieldValueOrError (/Users/rkuhar/work/api-gateway/node_modules/graphql/execution/execute.js:531:18)
```

How can I get a string representation of my array input into the graphql query string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to send the "input" param as **json body** instead of sending it in the *query string* itself.  You can `JSON.stringify` the input array separate from the query string.

Comment: Nah.  That won't work right there.  Note how the mutation call isn't actually JSON.  I need some sort of "toString" on that frickin' array.

Comment: It turns out that, ultimately, this is a solution, albeit indirectly.   I changed my mutation query string to leverage query variables and let the TypeScript JSON object serialize the input (JSON.stringify).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `console.log` calls toString() on arrays, but it seems that string interpolation does based on the error. As you've seen, you can pass an array to `console.log`, and it will output in a readable form. If you to call `input.toString()` you will see something like:

`"[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"`

I suspect this is not a valid value for your graphql query. You may need to convert it to an appropriate value before passing it in to the interpolation.

Comment: It is a valid graphQL query (I've been running that exact query through GraphiQL on the upstream service all along)...I just need the String value of that input array.  You're reasoning is correct, though.  Changing the console.log call to be `console.log(inputs.toString());` just presents the TypeError stacktrace before the string interpolation.  Thanks, but no joy.  How do I "stringify" the inputs array?

Comment: If you’re just trying to get a string representation of the array, you should be able to use JSON.stringify(input)